# MongoDB query result returns an array of arrays of dictionaries. I need only an array of dictionaries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need the value of the "browser" key in my result to be an array of dictionaries.  My current query returns an array of arrays of dictionaries which is not what I want.

1. How would I change/modify my query to get the value of the "browser" key to be just an array of dictionaries?
2. Is there a better way to pass the browser data from the first group to the second group in my aggregate query?

Below is my data, my query, and my current result:

#### Data Format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52f11293ed50ed92d0324755"),
    "major" : "26",
    "site_domain" : "www.google.com",
    "user_id" : "34850348039485093455445434",
    "timestamp" : "1390953411",
    "browser_name" : "Firefox",
}
```

#### Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group:{_id: {user_id:"$user_id", site_domain:"$site_domain"}, browser: {$addToSet:{name:"$browser_name", type:"$major"}}, browsing_history: {$addToSet:"$timestamp"}}}, 
                        {$group:{_id: {user_id:"$_id.user_id"}, browser:{$addToSet:"$browser"}, sites_visited:{$addToSet:{ site:"$_id.site_domain", times:"$browsing_history"}}}});
```

#### Result:

```
    {
        "_id" : {
            "user_id" : "ab93680ffb1b9c2"
        },
        "browser" : [
            [
                {
                    "name" : "Firefox",
                    "type" : "20"
                }
            ]
         ],
         "sites_visited" : [
             {
                 "site" : "google.com",
                 "times" : [
                     [
                         "20140201105126",
                         "1167637060"
                     ]
                 ]
             }
         ]
}
```

**My ideal result for the "browser" key would be:**

```
   "browser" : [
            {
                "name" : "Firefox",
                "type" : "20"
            }
     ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got most of the way. Just add an [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in between. Remember that otherwise you are *pushing* an array onto another *array*.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id: {user_id:"$user_id", site_domain:"$site_domain"},
        browser: {$addToSet:{name:"$browser_name", type:"$major"}},
        browsing_history: {$addToSet:"$timestamp"}
    }},
    {$unwind: "$browser"},                 // de-normalize before next group 
    {$group:{
        _id: {user_id:"$_id.user_id"},
        browser:{$addToSet:"$browser"}, 
        sites_visited: 
           {$addToSet:{ site:"$_id.site_domain", times:"$browsing_history"}}
    }}
]);
```